# How to use a compressed sparse matrix as a training data in XGBClassifier?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy, xgboost

I have a pandas DataFrame that has 800 columns:

1. 20 columns (continuous features)  have been processed using MinMaxScaler
2. the rest of columns (categorical features) is the output of OneHotEncoding.

As a result, my DataFrame is a sparse matrix.

Now I should apply XGBClassifier in order to solve multi-class classification problem. However, I think that it would be a good idea to compress this DataFrame.

I found this method:

```
from numpy import array
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
# convert to sparse matrix (CSR method)
B = csr_matrix(A)
```

However, it is not clear how to use it with sklearn classifiers.
In general, is it a good idea to compress my DataFrame?

Comment: Some parts of `sklearn` can use `scipy sparse` matrices; check its documentation.

Comment: If you check XGBoost documentation you will see it accepts sparse matrices as input.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: Ok, but do you know how it deals with sparse matrices? Could you share a link?

Answer (score -2):

You can use Pandas DataFrame with XGBoost (Tested with XGBoost version 0.81).

Sample code with the assumption that `df` is a Pandas DataFrame with a column, `target`.

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

// ... your code in here ...

// Train-Test Split
train, test = train_test_split(df)
y_train = train["target"]
X_train = train.drop(["target"],axis=1)
y_test = test["target"]
X_test = test.drop(["target"],axis=1)

// Train model
model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question about sparse matrices?